# A SciFi from the 70s showing a suicide by electrocution

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

Back in the 70s in the western United States I watched a movie or TV series that I would have sworn on a stack of Bibles was *Space: 1999* with a scene like the following:

A woman, I believe possessed but I'm sure a brunette, pulls a pair of electrical wires (big wires, thick enough to grip easily in her hands) from the wall. Sparks fly and everyone is startled. Calmly looking at the assembled people she begins crawling her hands toward the top of the conductors, which when touched will kill her. She is making demands... but I can't remember what those demands are. People are begging her to stop, but her hands eventually reach the top of the thick conductors and she dies by electrocution.

Like I said, stack of Bibles, but I just finished watching both seasons of *Space: 1999* and the scene wasn't there. Granted, a teen's mind can be all over the place, but I'm assuming that the look and feel of the program, which I'm 99% sure I watched on television, had a look and feel similar to Season 1 of *Space: 1999.*

Comment: Was this a serious scene or comic?  I'm getting a *Blazing Saddles* vibe from your description.

Comment: @DavidW Blazing saddles-esque it was not. The scene was intended to be serious (dramatic).

Comment: Did you watch this in the UK?  There were only three channels in the 1970s. It would be good info and would narrow the field. Also might be worth checking episodes of Sapphire and Steel and also UFO. Similar dates and I once misremembered scenes from Sapphire and Steel as being from 1999.

Comment: @skyjack, thank you for asking that, I've updated my post with the fact that I was in the western U.S. when I saw the program. However, I do remember watching British programming (Dr. Who, Blake's 7, etc.), so I can't rule those out. I'm working my way through UFO right now (but the "texture" doesn't feel right). I'll check into Sapphire and Steel, I don't recognize the name, but that doesn't mean anything at this point.

Comment: @JBH, you mention you watched both seasons of Space: 1999, but did you happen to check the four movie re-edits? Wikipedia indicates these "compilation films" had added scenes... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space:_1999#Compilation_films

Comment: @JamesDroscha I have not. I thought they simply re-edited the episodes and that new footage wasn't used. I'll track them down, but to be honest, I didn't find a story-arc in any episode that would lead to the scene I'm remembering. But... stranger things have happened. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @skyjack You were correct! It was an episode of UFO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**We have a winner!**

@Skyjack was correct, it is an episode of the British TV series [UFO](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0063962/?ref_=tt_ov_inf) (1970-1971): [The Psychobombs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Psychobombs)

[image]

Linda Simmonds, played by actress Deborah Grant, has her mind taken over by the Aliens. She charms Col. Paul Foster, played by Michael Billington, to gain access to SHADO control. There, she pulls out a pair of high voltage wires — her mission, to destroy SHADO control.

*The destruction mechanism was the influence of a landed UFO that turned the body into a bomb when high voltage is applied to it. Two earlier "bombs" (people) had successfully destroyed the Fairfield Tracker Station and SkyDiver 3 in this way.*

As Simmonds' hands inch up toward the exposed conduits, Straker begs her to stop, telling her the UFO had been destroyed, but the conditioning is too deep. The UFO had been destroyed, so when her hands touched the conductors, the high voltage killed her.

I was incorrect about the character being brunette, but I believe my misconception was excusable. SHADO control was under high alert, and all the lights were red, darkening both the acresses' hair and my memories of it.

Frankly, it was one of the more enjoyable episodes. Infinitely better than any episode in Season 2 of *Space: 1999.* Of course, watching asphalt degrade is better than most of the season 2 episodes of *Space:1999.*

Funny, the things that get stuck in your head as a kid.